# Align overlapping image in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align the play button image in the center of another image.

The example that I have is breaking when titles are long.

How can we align blue color image exactly over the large image

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w75vaho2/20/)

```
<div class="video-item-wrapper">
    <div class="video-image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="play-item-wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50.png/09f/fff&text=>" />
    </div>
    <div class="video-details-wrapper"> <span>this is video short video title</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your `play-item-wrapper` inside the container `video-image-wrapper` and add a relative positioning on it.

```
<div class="video-item-wrapper">
        <div class="video-image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="play-item-wrapper">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50.png/09f/fff&text=>" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="video-details-wrapper"> 
            <span>this is video short video title</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS

```
.video-image-wrapper { position: relative; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L51bd8vr/